# Vocal technique in the chorus of Stomp! by Brothers Johnson

Tags: vocal-range, falsetto

I am not a singer , however I am curious about this.

During the 1st Verse the singing sounds like falsetto to me.
During the 2nd Verse the singing still sounds very airy  , however it doesn`t sound like falsetto anymore ?

I have no ideea what happens during the chorus , It sounds like falsetto , but very huge... it is a lot of people singing falsetto at the same time ?  or maybe something else ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

I gave a listen to the song. George Johnson is not singing falsetto during the verse, not until the final ringing note of the line immediately preceding the chorus. Thats the natural upper range of his voice.

During the chorus, and you are right here, there are at least a half-dozen voices singing, and most of them are singing falsetto. I can clearly hear brother Louis Johnson singing falsetto on the chorus.

Comment: What happens during the verses ? It does not sound like a strong chest voice.... right ?

Comment: The video shows the band lip-synching to the original studio album song. Its my belief that George sang at a low-to-moderate volume in the studio, and you are right, that doesn't sound like a really strong chest voice. 

I have a high singing voice, and I can sing quite high without falsetto, on Johnny Nash's song I Can See Clearly Now, which my band performs in the key of D. 

Now, I do sing falsetto on The Lion Sleeps Tonight, which we lowered from the original key of F down to that of E. 

It's my belief that George does not go falsetto until the last ringing note of each verse.